# NoMethodError in Microposts#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nomethoderror

im having some trouble with my Ruby on Rails app.  I'm new at this so i imagine the problem isn't too complicated

Basically I am trying to create a discussion board.  the page /discussions has many discussions created by users who can make microposts to comment on them.  When I click the post button for the micropost form however, i get an error that reads

NoMethodError in Microposts#create

Showing /home/nick/Documents/RailsProjects/buon/app/views/shared/_discussion_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

any ideas?  heres some of the code

---

### micropost.rb

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :break_votes, :content, :not_votes
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :discussion


  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 200 }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :discussion_id, presence: true

  default_scope order: 'microposts.created_at DESC'
```

### end

### _discussions.html.erb

```
<% content_for :script do %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'hover_content' %>
<% end %>

<li>
  <div class = "intro-bar"><span class = "intro"><%=discussion.intro %></span></div>
  <div class = "content-bar">
   <span class = "content"><%= discussion.content %>
   <div class = "vote-plus"><%= link_to "Stay Together", signup_path,class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %></div>
    <div class = "vote-neg"><%= link_to "Break Up", signup_path,class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %></div>
   </span>
  </div>
  <span class = "timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(discussion.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>
</li>

<div class = "comments">
<% discussion.microposts.each do |micropost| %>
    <li>
      <div class = "post-comment"><%= micropost.content%></div>
    </li>
    <% end %>
</div>

<% if signed_in? %>
<div class = "row">
  <aside class = "span4">
    <section>
      <%= render 'shared/micropost_form', :locals => {:discussion => discussion }%>
    </section>
  </aside>
</div>
<% end %>
```

---

### micropost controller

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def index
  end

  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
     if @micropost.save
       flash[:success] = "Posted!"
       redirect_to root_url
     else
       render 'static_pages/home'
     end
  end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

---

### discussions_controller

```
class DiscussionsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update]


  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @discussions = @user.discussion.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @microposts = @user.micropost.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def index
    @discussions = Discussion.all
  end

  def create
    @discussion = current_user.discussions.build(params[:discussion])
    if @discussion.save
      flash[:success] = "Discussion Started!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
  end

  def new
  end
```

### end

### update: micropost_form

```
<% @micropost = Micropost.new %>
<% @micropost.discussion = nil %>

<%= form_for(@micropost) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new micropost..." %>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please share the partial `discussion_form.html.erb` where the proble occurs. Thank you!

Comment: <%= form_for(@discussion) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <div class="intro">
      <%= f.text_area :intro, placeholder: "Begin with an Intro" %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "and Write some Content" %>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>

Comment: Your `@discussion` variable is equal to `nil`

Comment: oic.  what is the solution tho that?

Comment: You need to set this `@discussion` variable in the `create` action of your `Microposts` controller. Something like `@discussion = current_user.discussions.new`

Comment: ok so i added the line to the top of the controller.  the error message goes away when i post but the microposts still dont show up

Comment: Probably micropost validation fails. Paste `shared/_micropost_form.html.erb` content.

You can also temporarily call @micropost.save! in Microposts#create - you will then probably have error explanation in your backtrace.

Comment: I added the form above.  thanks again for the help!

Comment: What exactly do you want to display in your `Discussions#show` action? One discussion? Because the code looks a bit weird. 
BTW, indeed, your micropost fails validation - you don't pass its discussion_id when you create it.